# How to deal with Latin characters for password validation using Regex expression?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am writing code for password validation which should have one Uppercase, one lowercase, One number and One special character from a given set. I wrote regex expression for this. I don't know how to take care of Latin characters like "ÏÐÑÜÝÞßàáâ". whether these latin characters will count in UpperCase or Lowercase or special characters.

```
  public const string NAME_REGEX = @"^[\da-zA-Z-+_*&=^%$#@(){}~!]{8,12}$";
```

Comment: In .net \w will allow all unicode characters in the 'letter' category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices,

1.You may account Latin characters as English characters and define your lowercase letters like this `[a-zà-ÿ]` and upper case letters as this `[A-ZÀ-ß]`. In this case presence of either English or Latin character will be accounted in the regex and according to your password rules, your regex can be written as this,

```
^(?=.*[a-zà-ÿ])(?=.*[A-ZÀ-ß])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$])[a-zà-ÿA-ZÀ-ß\d!@#$]{8,12}$
```

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/ceQ7M3/1)

Note here, I have restricted the allowed characters in password to this character set `[a-zà-ÿA-ZÀ-ß\d!@#$]` which you can enhance and allow further more characters or just write `.` to allow anything.

2.In second case, you may not want to account Latin characters in the password enforcement condition and hence you can take out those Latin characters from character set in look ahead expression. And your regex becomes this,

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$])[a-zà-ÿA-ZÀ-ß\d!@#$]{8,12}$
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/NQBjFu/1)

As you can see you can still allow Latin characters in allowed characters in password but it no longer participates in condition where at least one lower/upper case character has to be present in the password to it be valid.

Let me know if this helps else let me know for any queries further.